# Windows "known folders": is there any one of them which is reliably read/write for all users on all versions?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, known-folders

SHGetKnownFolderPath() and its cohorts accept one of the constants defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), returning the path to a directory.

I'm looking for one of these folders which is reliably writable by all users (including LocalSystem) on XP, Vista, and Windows 7... but I think I'm striking out.  It appears that, in fact, there is no single location on the hard drive anymore where you can put a file and be assured that all users can write to it on all these OS versions, without fiddling the permissions first.

Is this true?

Comment: What language are you using? C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; there is no such folder.

You will need to create one yourself.

Comment: If there's not already a folder you can write to already in all versions as a limited user, how do you do it without permissions fiddling on some version?

Comment: @RCIX: that  does seem to be a bit of a catch-22 at first, but I think SLaks is saying that the installation program (or something running as a non-limited or admin user for example) will need to arrange for a folder with the appropriate permissions for everyone to write to.

Comment: without testing all possibilities, I can't prove you're right, but I suspect that is true.  I can, of course, twiddle permissions, but was hoping to avoid having to do that.  It's not a crisis.  But as I was searching for this folder, I was struck by this realization: "there is really no public location on a Windows hard-drive anymore".  It used to be anybody could delete the whole operating system with a typo! :)

Answer (score 0):

One option seems to be `FOLDERID_PublicDocuments`, another could be `FOLDERID_ProgramData`. If there's a similar function you can use though to get a Documents type folder (for the user) that could work as well.

Edit: [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx) may help you.

Comment: Wrong; that's not writable by limited users.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked on 7 and Public Documents is writable by Everyone.

Comment: I just checked the Effective Permissions tab in Properties (also on Windows 7) and it isn't.

Comment: Also, if you look up the description for FOLDERID_ProgramData, you'll see that it is for application data for *all users*. It's kind of the point that everyone be able to write to it.

Comment: Something is messed up on your installation then, because mine shows Full Control checked off. I haven't touched that folder before.

Comment: What folder? I don't see that.

Comment: Odd, i checked Public Documents and SLaks is correct; no boxes are checked off when i input Everyone in the Effective Permissions security dialog.

Comment: Maybe mine is the messed up one.

Comment: Well thanks everybody for chiming in.  Guess I'll use my Plan B :)

Answer (score 0):

`%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`

This will not be writable by low-integrity processes or limited users, however.

Comment: Wrong; that's not writable by limited users.